# Remove an object in a std::vector by value

Tags: c++, oop, vector, stl

I would like to remove an object from a stl vector if it is present.

```
class test
{
    vector<Objects> myvector;

public:
        test();
        removeTest(Objects);
}

test::removeTest(Objects aObject)
{
    myvector.erase(remove(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), aTest),myvector.end());
}
```

However, whenever I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
no match for 'operator=='
```

This only occurs if I use an iterator through a vector of objects of type 'Objects'. I can get it to work for the case of looking for an integer then removing this.

Anyone know why I am getting these errors? And am I using the correct method to remove an object from a stl vector of objects by value?

Comment: You need to define an `==` operator, preferably with the signature of `bool operator==(test&& other) const`, or close. Right now, your vector has no way of actually finding the object you give.

Comment: The only way to identify an object instance by value is to identify the memory address of the instance. You can't `remove()` an object instance by memory address. If you define an `==` operator, it can compare whether two object instances are *equivalent* to each other by comparing the value of data members, like ID numbers.  Otherwise, you can use `remove_if()` instead.

Comment: Why not just use [`std::remove_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)?

Comment: Note: If your `Objects` is heavy to copy you have some problems. The vector needs to copy them around if one is removed. Also in your remove function you would need to construct an object to delete another object. You might want to take the parameter by value aswell. A better approach is to use a vector of pointers to objects. Preferable std::unique_ptr.

Answer (score 1):

> no match for 'operator=='

Error says it all. You need to provide an equality comparison for your `Object` class, `std::remove` can't otherwise know how to compare your objects to determine which ones need to be removed.

For example:

```
struct Object {
    int i;
    std::string s;

    bool operator==(const Object& rhs) const {
        return i == rhs.i && s == rhs.s;
    }
};
```

It worked for integers because equality comparison between integers is built-in. Not so for user-defined types.

With that, this:

```
    void test::removeTest(const Object& aObject)
//  ^^^^                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
    {
        myvector.erase(
            remove(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), aObject),
//                                                   ^^^^^^^
            myvector.end()
            );
    }
```

Should do exactly what you want. Note that you were missing a return type for `removeTest` (I'm assuming you want `void`) and you should take the object you want to remove by reference-to-const to avoid the unnecessary copy.

Comment: That's great. Thanks. I would actually like to compare the objects by checking that their pointers point to the same address in memory. Could you advise on this?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I want to check equivalence by checking that pointers to the objects match. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ben18785 with `vector<Object*>` maybe, but with `vector<Object`> `remove_if` will shift the contents as it goes so your pointers will change.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I suspect it will be better (and faster) to work with a vector of pointers. Thanks again!